# Cast MyClass<T_Enum> to MyClass<Enum>

Tags: c#, enums

Have the usecase that I want a struct which can host a generic type.
It needs to be possible to store instances of the struct with different types in a common list.
Then I want to iterate over that list and execute different code depending on the generic type.

This works all fine with int, double, string etc. But it fails on generic enums. It only works on a specific enum.

See the following code (or a Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/7Cz0Te ) please:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    
public class Program
{
    internal interface ILinkedParam
    {}
    internal struct LinkedParam<Param_T> : ILinkedParam
    {
        public Param_T param;
    }
    
    enum AnEnum
    {
        option_a, option_b
    }
    
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<ILinkedParam> parameters = new List<ILinkedParam>();
        parameters.Add(new LinkedParam<double>() {param=20.5});
        parameters.Add(new LinkedParam<bool>() {param=true});
        parameters.Add(new LinkedParam<AnEnum>() {param=AnEnum.option_a});
        Process(parameters);
    }
    static private void Process(List<ILinkedParam> parameters)
    {
         foreach (ILinkedParam ptr in parameters)
         {
             LinkedParam<double>? double_param = ptr as LinkedParam<double>?;
             if (double_param != null)
             {
                 var prm = double_param.Value;
                 Console.WriteLine("Processed a DOUBLE with value: " + prm.param.ToString());
                 continue;
             }

             LinkedParam<bool>? bool_param = ptr as LinkedParam<bool>?;
             if (bool_param != null)
             {
                 var prm = bool_param.Value;
                 Console.WriteLine("Processed a BOOL with value: " + prm.param.ToString());
                 continue;
             }

     
             LinkedParam<Enum>? generic_enum_param = ptr as LinkedParam<Enum>?;
             if (generic_enum_param != null)
             {
                 var prm = generic_enum_param.Value;
                 Console.WriteLine("Processed a GENERIC ENUM with value: " + prm.param.ToString());
                 continue;
             }
             else
                 Console.WriteLine("No generic enum.");
                 
             
             LinkedParam<AnEnum>? fixed_enum_param = ptr as LinkedParam<AnEnum>?;
             if (fixed_enum_param != null)
             {
                 var prm = fixed_enum_param.Value;
                 Console.WriteLine("Processed a FIXED ENUM with value: " + prm.param.ToString());
                 continue;
             }
        }

    }
}
```

It currently prints

```
Processed a DOUBLE with value: 20.5
Processed a BOOL with value: True
No generic enum.
Processed a FIXED ENUM with value: option_a
```

But I'd like it to print:

```
Processed a DOUBLE with value: 20.5
Processed a BOOL with value: True
Processed a GENERIC ENUM with value: option_a
```

Any suggestions? Huge thanks!